# JSF/XSP NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jsf

I am trying to set up a XPage application, which is JSF based. In one of the controllers I am trying to use a global defined bean:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>servicePositionBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>beans.ServicePositionBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
```

The point where I assume it fails:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
return context.getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(context, "servicePositionBean");
```

The error I am getting:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: beans/ServicePositionBean
    com.sun.faces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:142)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.initBeforeContents(UIViewRootEx.java:1621)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:333)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createViewRoot(AbstractCompiledPage.java:167)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:521)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:567)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:142)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
```

I am 100% sure that the bean is correctly defined and in the directory.

Comment: are you doing any initialisation in the bean's constructor?

Comment: if so is it possible an exception is occurring there?

Comment: @CameronGregor The changes in the database were not signed -.-